# Can we use same auth cookie (generated in dot net core api) in a different api applications but in the same domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, webapi

I have an application(core 2.2.0) which uses a cookie for authentication, below is the code from the Startup.cs file

```
services.AddAuthentication(cookieConfig.AuthScheme)
    .AddCookie(cookieConfig.AuthScheme, options => {
        options.LoginPath = new PathString(cookieConfig.LoginPath);
        options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString(cookieConfig.AccessDeniedPath);
        options.Cookie = cookie;
        options.Events = cookieEvents;
    });
```

And below code is from the Sign-in API

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(_cookieConfig.AuthScheme, userPrincipal, authProps);
```

Suppose this application generates a cookie 'ABC', and it has a URL1 - https://somedomain.com/api
and I have another API hosted at URL2 - https://somedomain.com/another_api/whatever
But remember both APIs are a different project.
When I pass this cookie to URL1, in the OnAuthorization() I can see the Identities and the Claims properties with correct values of that user and it authorizes the user perfectly. But when I pass the same cookie to URL2 all claims and identity properties show null and it does not authorize.

My question: Is it possible to share authentication between different domains? If yes, then how? If not possible then please suggest an alternative approach.

**Additional Details** -
We have the above code which generates (at App1) a cookie ABC=some_encrpyted_value.

And in App2 I am trying to unprotect that cookie in below manner

```
string cookieValue = context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["ABC"];
var provider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp-keys\"));

var dataProtector = provider.CreateProtector(typeof(CookieAuthenticationMiddleware).FullName, "ABC", "v2");
UTF8Encoding specialUtf8Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false, throwOnInvalidBytes: true);
byte[] protectedBytes = Base64UrlTextEncoder.Decode(cookieValue);
byte[] plainBytes = dataProtector.Unprotect(protectedBytes);
string plainText = specialUtf8Encoding.GetString(plainBytes);
TicketDataFormat ticketDataFormat = new TicketDataFormat(dataProtector);
AuthenticationTicket ticket = ticketDataFormat.Unprotect(cookieValue);
```

I have placed the data protection key from App1 in the folder 'C:\temp-keys'.

I found this code somewhere in StackOverflow itself and it throws 'CryptographicException: The payload was invalid.' exception at line

```
byte[] plainBytes = dataProtector.Unprotect(protectedBytes);
```

My understanding of the App1 code is that the Identity and Claim values (with some other values) are encrypted and cookie ABC is generated, and when we send a request this cookie is decrypted and the Identity and Claims are get populated in the context.HttpContext.User
I actually wanted it to work the same way in the App2, I want to pass the cookie and the identity values should be populated in the context.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. To deal with this type of scenarios we have been using ASP.NET machineKey. That is does is it encrypts/descriptor the auth data using the same key so that different sites can share the same authenticated sessions and data.

In Dotnet Core this `machineKey` concept has evolved and now called - new data protection `system. Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.SystemWeb` package is used to implement the data protection system. To [read more on this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/compatibility/replacing-machinekey?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

There are various ways how you can store and use the key:

- ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault (if you are using Azure)
- [PersistKeysToFileSystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1#persistkeystofilesystem) (this is the easier one)
- ProtectKeysWith*
- UnprotectKeysWithAnyCertificate

Details of the individual scenario is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it helped a lot. But I am again stuck while unprotecting the data in the other application, It gives an exception 'CryptographicException : The payload was invalid.'

Comment: @SachinSaklani Can you share relevant codes from both applications? Add the new information to the bottom of the question. Do not delete the initial question.

Comment: Did that. Please let me know if it is insufficient.